# How to set a CSSClass for a dynamically generated label?

Tags: c#

How to set a CSSClass for a dynamically generated label in asp.net with C#

Answer (score 4):

```
Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.Text = "Hello World!";
lbl.CssClass = "red_and_bold";
```

Answer (score 0):

When You create Label then set its CssClass property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you mean setting it server-side you can use WebControl.CssClass property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Label lblPrivacyGender = new Label();
lblPrivacyGender.Attributes.Add("class", "spanHeaderStyle");
lblPrivacyGender.Text = "Gender: ";

Above spanHeaderStyle is a CssClass which is previously defined